# Not sending XML command with header via TCP/IP using Java

Tags: java, xml, sockets, tcp, request

I'm new to Java (basically had to learn it on the fly for this project), but I'm trying to send an XML command to a server to get some data from it. To do this, I've written a Java program and I'm running it from the command line.

Here's my Java code for a reference. I got most of this from a client/server TCP tutorial and adjusted the IP, port, and outgoing message accordingly. Again, I'm very new to this, so any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class GDC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Attempting connection to GE Reuter Stokes");

        // establish the socket connection to the server
        // using the local IP address, if server is running on some other IP, use that 
        Socket socket = new Socket(<SERVER_IP>, <SERVER_PORT>);
        System.out.println("Socket Connected");

        // write to socket using OutputStream
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        // Initializing request content
        byte[] request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><command version=\"2.2\" cmd=\"HEARTBEAT\"/>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // DataOutputStream.writeInt() writes in big endian and
        // DataInputStream.readInt() reads in big endian.
        // using a ByteBuffer to handle little endian instead.

        byte[] header = new byte[5];
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(header, 1, 4);
        buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        // Initializing request header
        header[0] = (byte) 0x060E2B34;
        header[1] = (byte) 0x02050101;
        header[2] = (byte) 0x0F150111;
        header[3] = (byte) 0x00000000;
        buf.putInt(request.length);

        System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server"); 

        // Sending request
        dos.write(header);
        dos.write(request);
        dos.flush();

        System.out.println("Request was sent. Awaiting response.");

        // read from socket using InputStream
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

        // Read response header
        dis.readFully(header);
        buf.flip();

        // Read response content
        byte[] response = new byte[buf.getInt()];
        dis.readFully(response);

        // convert the content into a string
        String message = new String(response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);

        // close your resources
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();

        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I want to send XML request using the following instruction :

[image: Screenshot Instructions]

**I got an error like follow:**

```
Attempting connection to GE Reuter Stokes
Socket Connected
Sending request to Socket Server
Request was sent. Awaiting response.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
        at GDC.main(GDC.java:54)
```

Comment: That's just an error showing that you haven't imported `java.nio.ByteOrder`. Add that import and the error will go away. Whenever you see a "cannot find symbol" error, you should look at what symbol hasn't been found, and think about where you *expected* it to be found. I have no idea whether the rest of your code is correct, but that's the solution for that particular error.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine now.

Comment: Still, I want to know either the code is correct or not.

Comment: Then that's a question for codereview.stackexchange.com. Do you have any reason to think it's *not* correct? Have you tested it?

Comment: We can't tell if the code is correct.  Every server is different in the format and type of message.  Java uses HTTP (request and a response).  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  If server requires HTTPS (secure) than SSL needs to be used which is perfomred using TCP (before the http is sent).  A HTTP request can have a header indicating the body will be XML, but the documentation for the server would have to indicate exactly what the body should contain and the tags.

Comment: @JonSkeet: On Code Review it is expected that the “code works correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge.” Any question mentioning “I got an error” or asking if “the code is correct or not” will most probably be closed quickly.

Comment: @MartinR: The "I got an error" wouldn't be in there now. But I see your point on the rest.